# Recursive Tribonacci Sequence Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

How do you calculate the time complexity of the recursive tribonacci function `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + F(n-3)` with base cases `F(0) = 0, F(1) = F(2) = 1`?

Comment: Time complexity : O(n) . Size of recursion tree can go upto N (the size) with memo or DP method.

Comment: @DanielHao without Memoization or DP, how do we calculate the time complexity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to use induction to prove it's `O(1.84^(n-1))`.
`T(n) = 1` when `n <= 2` and `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)` when `n > 2`.

**Base case:**
`T(3) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3`
`T(3) = 1.84^2 ≈ 3`
`T(3) = O(1.84^(n-1))`

**Inductive case:** Assume `T(n-1) = 1.84^(n-2)`. Then,
`T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)`
`T(n) = 1.84^(n-2) + 1.84^(n-3) + 1.84^(n-4)`
`T(n) ≈ 1.84^(n-1)`
`T(n) = O(1.84^(n-1))`

If you want it to be exact, use the [tribonacci constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers) instead, but it's tedious to show it is equal. However, I can edit this to show it if you want.